# How I can extract files, name.iso.001 name.iso.002 and so on

Tags: file-format, iso, extract

I just downloaded some materials, but the extensions are not recognized by Ubuntu.

I have a bunch of files names `name.iso.001`, `name.iso.002` and so on.

How I can extract or mount it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cat name.iso.001 name.iso.002 so on > newName.iso
```

does the job almost all the time.
Otherwise there is utility called lxsplit

```
sudo apt-get install lxsplit
```

I never used lxsplit but I think the way you use it to join is:

```
lxsplit -j name.iso.001
```

Comment: Was going to say the same thing.

Comment: I got u :) but yea when I transitted from Windows to Ubuntu this particular issue was quite dominant

Comment: what about `cat filename.avi.* > filename.avi`?

Answer (score 0):

These filenames look like those produced in Windows by QuickPar when used to split files (particularly video files including iso files) and can be rejoined by Quickpar and repaired at same time if needed with par files supplied.

I used WINE to install QuickPar in Ubuntu and used it to join the files. I think only Quickpar can rejoin what it has split.