# How to Open .001 .002 .003 and .r01 .r02 .r03 RAR Files

Tags: windows, files, compression, rar, split

Is `WinRAR` the same as Linux `rar`?  Additional features?  Missing features?  Special way of handling files?

> Software is available for Microsoft Windows (named WinRAR), Linux...

-wikipedia

The context is files [which are split](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-open-001-002-003-and-r01-r02-r03-rar-files):

> Sometimes you'll download a large file and find that instead of the
>   single file you wanted, your folder is full of .001 .002 .003 or .r01
>   .r02 .r03 files. These files are part of a split RAR archive. Much
>   like a zip file, a RAR file is a compressed version of what you
>   downloaded. Rather than transmit in a single file, it's spread out
>   over these several files -- usually to speed downloading or to
>   accommodate the file size limit of a commercial file storage host.

I'm **not** asking how to `unrar` files.  I'm asking:  why are these files named so?  Is this a Windows convention, or also Linux?  Is this just a "split" [file](https://askubuntu.com/q/213787/45156)?

Not inclined to install `WINE` solely [to](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029073/45156) install `QuickPar`.

These specific files are named with this pattern:

```
foo bar - baz.rar.001
```

complete with the spacees and hyphens between foo, bar, baz.

Not named .r01, just 001.  If that makes a difference.  (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to Open .001 .002 .003 and .r01 .r02 .r03 RAR Files

rar takes care of this by itself. You `unrar` the file without the extension and it will scan for all the files it needs to recreate the original file.

> Is WinRAR the same as Linux rar?

Winrar is a clone of rar for Windows.

> Additional features? Missing features? Special way of handling files?

```
man rar
```

to see all features of rar.

> I'm asking: why are these files named so?

Because we have media that have a limited storage capacity. If you want to save a 10Gb large movie  on a ...

- 3.5 inch you'd need 720Kb, 1.44Mb or 2.88Mb large files. You need a lot of disks. 7367...
- cd rom drive you would need files roughly 700Mb. So 14 files to go on 14 CDs.
- a dvd drive you would need files roughly 4.7Gb for a single-layer or 8.5Gb for a dual-layer disk. You'd need 3 or 2 dvds.

Nowadays there is no more need to split files though. And BD drives are pretty common and those started with 25Gb and can go up to roughly 3Tb.

But this all became obsolete due to larger disks and online storage.

> Is this just a "split" file?

Yes.

> Not named .r01, just 001. If that makes a difference. (?)

It is the same. You can make your own extensions. It is also possible to do .aaa through .zzz as an extension to the filename.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter answer that works great.

1. Go to the rar editor's website and download the single distrib "linux" (a tar.gz file).

2.unzip it with your native system (i had ubuntu),

3. then go to that directory and type "./unrar myfile.part1.rar" and that's going to work like a breeze. Thanks to the Editor !!